# Java Can I reduce this snippet to less lines? Prompt and Input on same line?

Tags: java, syntax

I'm experimenting with writing code with as few commands as possible. This is helping me find various overloads of methods. In code snippet below I ask user for 2 numbers then output various math results. Code works fine. Any suggestions for how to make tighter, less lines?

Is it possible to print a "prompt" directly from the input line? I couldn't find that option from my NetBeans pop-up selection.
Thanks.

```
public static void calculatorTight() {
    // do calcs in printf() command
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);        
    System.out.print("Please enter first number: ");
    float numberOne = kb.nextFloat();
    System.out.print("Please enter second number: ");
    float numberTwo = kb.nextFloat();
    System.out.printf("For numbers %.2f and %.2f:\nSum=%.2f\nDiff=%.2f"
            + "\nProduct=%.2f \nQuotent=%.2f \nModulo=%.2f"
            + "\nSquare root first=%.2f \nSquare root second=%.2f\n"
            ,numberOne,numberTwo,numberOne+numberTwo, numberOne-numberTwo 
            ,numberOne*numberTwo,numberOne/numberTwo, numberOne%numberTwo
            ,Math.sqrt(numberOne),Math.sqrt(numberTwo));// end print    
}//calculatorTight
```

Comment: I don't understand your goal - please explain. You could implement your own method which combines these steps for you, but I think this isn't the answer you need?

Comment: You could write a function called `promptFloat(Scanner scanner, String message)`. That would reduce the number of statements. The function might add an extra line or two though

Comment: Hate to say it, but I'm going to add a line for you !  Make it a habit to always close things like Scanners, otherwise it can cause a leak.  The scanner will get garbage-collected, but that won't close the file that it's reading from (although not an issue in this particular case).  So you should add "kb.close()", or better yet, create kb in a try-with-resources block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a loop something like:

```
public static void calculatorTight(String[] prompts, float[] vals) {
    // do calcs in printf() command
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in); 
    for(int i = 0; i < prompts.length; i++){
        System.out.print(prompts[i]);
        vals[i] = kb.nextFloat();
    }
    ...
}//calculatorTight
```

Though the final print statement gets more complicated, so this may not be worth it.

Comment: Thanks for ideas. I considered a function for input but with only 2 values coming in, I couldn't get the function tighter than what I'm doing with 4 lines in main code. I was wondering if there was a way to print a prompt as an argument of the input's methods. (Like in VB input box.) That would make one command of show message and receive input. But looks like not. Thanks much for your thoughts.

Comment: You could make a function to do that, but its really just going to be the same code.

Answer (score 0):

When using graphical UI, you can use 
    String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(string);